# Connect a kernel socket to stdin and stdout

Tags: sockets, kernel

I am working on a kernel root-kit for my Malware analysis class, one of the features of this root-kit is to create a reverse shell connection to the attacker's PC. I know how to create this in user space but, in kernel space is a different ball game.

I am able to create sockets in kernel space and spawn user application from within the kernel, but I cannot connect the socket to STDIN or STDOUT, in user space I would simply use dup2(), but I cannot do it  kernel space. I am required to do this kernel space. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am aware that the socket structure contains a pointer to file struct, I am not sure if this is of any relevance to my project, the source code for linux/fs.h is not very helpful on providing information.

Comment: `in user space I would simply use dup2(), but I cannot do it kernel space.` - Why you cannot use `dup2()` in the kernel? It is implemented in [fs/file.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/fs/file.c#L943). (Implementation is forwarded to `dup3`, which is implemented above).

Comment: thats a good point, how do I i use do_dup2(), the function declaration is very different from the user space version.

Comment: im sorry if I sound stupid, I don't have much experience writing network applications in kernel space

Comment: There is no much difference with user space: declaration of syscall function is read as `unsigned long sys_dup2(unsigned int oldfd, unsigned int newfd)`.